# Angular text binding on multiple condition

Tags: angular

I could bind text on single condition as this `<ion-label>{{company ? company.name : 'Select a company'}}</ion-label>`

How ca I use multiple condition in this? like,
`<ion-label>{{company || organization ? company.name : 'Select a company'}}</ion-label>`

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Whay are you using `"` to wrap interpolation?

Comment: remove the `""`

Comment: Why are you using `"` ??

Comment: try to create get property or function and do code in that and use that in your html

Comment: I am sorry, i don't use `"` it is `<ion-label>{{company ? company.name : 'Select a company'}}</ion-label>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign to some variable first in controller part like this -

```
myValue = this.company || this.organization;
<ion-label>{{myValue ? myValue?.name : 'Select a company'}}</ion-label>
```

PS: Also no need to wrap your variable into interpolation syntax using `"`.

Answer (score 1):

if you have multiple condition then you should make use of function instead of doing it in html

```
<ion-label>{{getLable(input)}}</ion-label>

getLabel(input){

  return "text";
}
```

Easy manage complex condition in code file rather then html.

Comment: This approach would be much better to avoid complex condition checking on view side (HTML)